# SST12LP15B: What is the purpose of the length/width specification for connecting pin 12 (VCC3) to VCC?

Tags: layout, power-amplifier

In the datasheet for the [SST12LP15B](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70005029C.pdf), figure 11 shows that pin 12  (VCC3 - power supply, third stage) is connected to VCC via a "Length = 220 mil,
Width = 10 mil" trace. Why is this required? Is it some sort of impedance matching?
When routing, do I need to make sure that the trace connecting pin 12 to VCC is 220 mil long and 10 mil wide? What would the effect of not adding this trace length/width be?

[image]

Comment: Not familiar with that part, but my guess is it's meant to reflect microwave frequencies that couple into the power line.